# missing expression in case statement

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I've been trying to nest my case statements but I'm getting a "missing expression" error. Below is a snippet of my code. Thanks!

```
sum(case when app_count =1 then status_month end, then case when sysdate-1 >= add_months(status_month,1) and status_date <= add_months(status_month,1)
     then enroll_count else 0 end) as enrl1mnth,

sum(case when app_count =1 then status_month end, then case when sysdate-1 >= add_months(status_month,2) and status_date <= add_months(status_month,2)
     then enroll_count else 0 end) as enrl2mnth,
```

.
.
.
So on and so forth

Comment: Get rid of the extra `end, the case` in the middle: `sum(case when app_count =1 then status_month when sysdate-1 >= add_months(status_month,1) and status_date <= add_months(status_month,1)
     then enroll_count else 0 end) as enrl1mnth,`

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I tried that however I got the following error.
inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: One of those is a date and the other is a number. If you really want that then you'll probably need to use `to_char()` to convert them to strings.

Comment: Oh alright. Thanks again!